# Coordinate Transformation and Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, fluid-dynamics, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm currently working on an assignment where I end up with the following differential equation in cylindrical coordinates:

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial w_\varphi}{\partial r}\right), $$

where $r$ is the radius and $w_\varphi$ describes the angular velocity of a stirred liquid.

If I assume $r$ to be a "regular" variable and I apply the chain rule I get the following equation:

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial r^2}r + \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \tag{1} $$

The last task of the assignment is to compare the results of this equation with the results obtained from simplifying the Navier-Stokes equation (basically the holy grail of fluid mechanics) and to explain possible differences. The equation I obtain from the Navier-Stokes equation looks like this:

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial^2w}{\partial r^2} r + \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} - \frac{w}{r} \tag{2} $$

so I get an extra $-\frac{w}{r}$ out of it.

I'm fairly certain that both equations are correct, or at least the intended outcome of their task, because my professor said that everything was looking good up until now.

The question is of course where does this extra $-\frac{w}{r}$ come from?

My professor gave me the hint of looking at the $r$ variable more closely and to try and think of how  it would change in carthesian coordinates. Or to look at it in a vector form, so using  $\vec{r} = \begin{pmatrix} r \> cos(\varphi)\\r \> sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$ instead of just $r$ to account for the moving unit vectors in cylindrical coordinates.

To be honest my courses in calculus happened quite a while ago and I forgot a good portion of them so I'm a bit confused by this problem and don't really know where to begin. If anyone has an idea on how to solve or approach this problem I would be very grateful.

EDIT:

Upon further research I found a chapter out of an ODE Textbook in which it seems the same or at least a similar problem is posed as an exercise. Unfortunately I couldn't find any solutions for the exercises of the book, but maybe it can shed some light into what my question is.

[https://faculty.missouri.edu/~chiconec/pdf/water1.pdf](https://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Echiconec/pdf/water1.pdf)

The exercise in question is 6.7

Comment: What I'm guessing your professor was hinting at is at a decay law for linear sources, which decay inversely with the radial distance from the source. Similar to if you were to do the spherical transformation, it would result in a $\frac{1}{r^2}$ term

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The equation and the results do make sense in my opinion. But the problem I'm sitll having is that i can't figure out, where the term -w/r is coming from mathematically. So what operations do I have to do to get from the first to the third euquation?

Comment: I've never taken a fluid mechanics course, so could you explain what/how you got the first PDE? Because your first equation is equivalent (by product rule) to the second, and there's no way to force a $w/r$ term to appear from there. So, if indeed you're supposed to get a $w/r$ term, it means the first equation has to be incorrect.

Comment: (1) Okay, I'll give it a go. So the equation comes from a differential Impuls balance in cylindrical coordinates in an annular gap an comes down to $0=\frac{\partial \tau A(r)}{\partial r}$ where $\tau$ is the shearstress and A(r) is the surface area on which the stress is applied (since I'm considering ist as a 2D probelm its just the circumference at $r$). The shearstress for a Newtonian fluid is calculated as $\tau = \eta \frac{\partial w}{\partial r}$, where $\eta$ is the viscosity (constant for this problem) and $w$ is the angular velocity, I'm looking for.

Comment: So I'm getting $0=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\eta 2 \pi r \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \right)$ and when all the constants cancel out I'm left with the equation from above: $0=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial w_\varphi}{\partial r}\right)$. I'm not sure this helped,. As I said before I'm pretty sure the equation is correct since that's how we've always done it, which makes me even more confused about the two different outcomes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that fluid mechanics course should be over by now.